# pyqt5 - widget focus does not behave according to setTabOrder

Tags: pyqt5

I have a simple issue but I can't get out of it: I have set the tab order for the widgets within a form but, despite the tab order in the code is correct, when the form is displayed such order is not respected. Specifically after the widget 'self.dateEdit' pressing tab key, rather than moving the focus to 'self.comboBox' widget it goes to 'self.doubleSpinBox' widget. Below is the code
Any idea why ? Thanks

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
    Dialog.resize(474, 433)
    self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
    self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
    self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
    self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(Dialog)
    self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.dateEdit)
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
    self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
    self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox)
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
    self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
    self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox_2)
    self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
    self.doubleSpinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(Dialog)
    self.doubleSpinBox.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.doubleSpinBox)
    self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_6)
    self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
    self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
    self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.textEdit)
    self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout)
    self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
    self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
    self.buttonBox.setCenterButtons(False)
    self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
    self.label.setBuddy(self.lineEdit)
    self.label_5.setBuddy(self.doubleSpinBox)

    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) # type: ignore
    self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject) # type: ignore
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    Dialog.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit, self.dateEdit)
    Dialog.setTabOrder(self.dateEdit, self.comboBox)
    Dialog.setTabOrder(self.comboBox, self.comboBox_2)
    Dialog.setTabOrder(self.comboBox_2, self.doubleSpinBox)
    Dialog.setTabOrder(self.doubleSpinBox, self.textEdit)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Employee &Name"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Employee Date"))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Department"))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Position"))
    self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Annual &Salary"))
    self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Job Description"))
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe using the current code in your question. For me, the tab order works exactly as expected (i.e. name > date > dept > pos).

Comment: I found the problem: for some reasons the 2 combo boxes did not have the property 'editable' enabled. Thanks anyway

Comment: That sounds like a bug, or some weird platform-specific quirk. Either that, or the code in the question is not the same as what you are actually running. The combo-boxes should get the keyboard focus regardless of whether they are editable or not.